# How can I extract my log4j.properties file outside of .WAR file?

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, log4j

I'm using **spring boot** in my project. And in the package **resources** I have **log4j.properties** file which works very fine and expected.

But now, I want somehow to override this **log4j.properties** file from outside of .WAR file and I had tried to find some solutions in the internet, but I can't.

And the strange thing is:
I can override **application.properties** file when I'm running **Tomcat** just putting another **application.properties** file in the **Tomcat** package **conf**. And also I add only one line into **context.xml** file:

```
<Context>
        <Environment name="spring.config.location" value="../conf/" type="java.lang.String" override="true"/>
</Context>
```

But this approach is inappropriate for **log4j.properties** file. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `logging.config` property to define logging configuration file location.

> `logging.config=` #Location of the logging configuration file. For instance `classpath:logback.xml` for Logback

The second property is `logging.path` it specifies the location of the log file.

> `logging.path=` # Location of the log file. For instance `/var/log`